# Proxy objects and return types conflict

Tags: magento2, php-7, proxy

Magento is designed to use PHP 7, newest versions even 7.1. Actually one of the most killing feature - return types doesn't work well with Magento implementation of `Proxy object`.

For example I create `proxy` for some dependency of class. This dependency has a few methods and at least one of them contains return type. It will fail later as the `proxy` won't copy return type at all, and declarations of methods in original and `proxy` class won't match. Has some figured out something to make it work? Or is it question for core team as request for bug fix?

Answer (score 1):

It is a question for core team as a request for improvement ;).

Or as better solution, you can fix it by self and contribute it to Magento over Pull Request

Answer (score 1):

This has been annoying me for some time now as well. Magento 2.3.0 is now only a week away and as I understand it, the solution will shipped there: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Code/Generator/Proxy.php#L186 In short, proxy generation will include the proper return types declared in the original source.

The current code in Magento 2.3 is a bit more complex, but you can hack something equal in your source (err, no argument here) by modifying the `_getMethodInfo` method of the `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Proxy` class. And then, in the `$methodInfo` add a line like `'returnType' => $method->getReturnType(),`. That being said, hacking the core is pointless but a similar solution will be shipped in Magento 2.3.

Comment: Agreed, pointless at current time :)

Answer (score 0):

@Jisse @KAndy, actually I have checked that in 2.3.0 by myself and I confirm, that this is working. What is more I even contribute and fixed code for case when variadic argument in proxied class method is used.